# Why is the zero locus of a polynomial ideal a variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, zariski-topology

I'm sorry if this is a stupid question, but some books define a variety of an ideal as it's zero locus, what means that it's irreducible. I'm just new to algebra and wasn't able to prove it... Can someone help me, please?

Comment: "Variety" implies irreducible in some books but not in others. If you take an arbitrary ideal in the polynomial ring then its zero locus has no reason to be irreducible, so it will be hard to prove this!

Comment: To reiterate: it's hard to figure out what you're asking but if I'm interpreting you correctly then what you want is simply not true; the confusion is caused by inconsistent terminology among books.

Comment: Thanks for answering. You're right, I thought that was proposital their use of the word "variety". One more question: is there any condition on the generators of an ideal that could imply on it's zero locus to be irreducible? Or any set of generators that give me a prime ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your definition of a variety is the following:

> **Definition.** Let $k$ be a field, $d$ be an integer greater than $1$ and $V$ be a subset of $k^d$. $V$ is a variety if and only if there exists $f_1,\cdots,f_n$ in $k[X_1,\cdots,X_d]$ such that: $$V=\{x\in k^d\textrm{ s.t. }\forall i\in\{1,\cdots, n\},f_i(x)=0.\}.$$

Let $I$ be an ideal of $K[X_1,\cdots,X_d]$ and let $Z(I):=\{x\in k^d\textrm{ s.t. }\forall f\in I,f(x)=0\}$, you want to show that $Z(I)$ is a variety. Your problem is that $I$ is not a finite set. Can you show that:

- $I$ is generated by a finite number of polynomials, let say $f_1,\cdots,f_n$.
- $Z(I)=\{x\in k^d\textrm{ s.t. }\forall i\in\{1,\cdots, n\},f_i(x)=0\}.$

Comment: First, thanks for answering. Actually my definition is yours plus the item "V is (Zariski) irreducible", which is also my problem... I want to show that Z(I) satisfies this last condition.

Comment: I think you mean "variety," not "manifold." A manifold is something else.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, that was a bad translation on my part.